# How to define job execution order in Talend Open Studio

Tags: etl, talend

Is there any way to define jobs execution order in Talend open studio?

For example: job1 -> job2 -> job3 ...

There is a component named tParallelize in the Talend suite, but it's not available for Talend Open Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The great thing about Talend is that any job can be called from within another job using `tRunJob` component, so what you want can be achieved by creating a master job, and inside it, calling your jobs in the order you want:

```
tRunJob_1 (job1)
   |
OnSubjobOk
   |
tRunJob_2 (job2)
   |
  ...
   |
tRunJob_n (jobX)
```

This ensures that your jobs are called in that order, and call the next job only if the previous job executed successfully.
tParellelize is used to run jobs in parallel, so it's not the same thing.